# How to evaluate an expression-tree in sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

This might be a very basic question, but I am wondering if I am missing a sympy-functionality after reading through the documentation, or if there is really non included for this use-case.

I have the following expressions:

```
a = sympify("b + 5")
b = sympify("c + 5")
c = sympify("5")
```

I am trying to evaluate a. 
Is there any way that sympy does all the recursive search and replace for you or do I really have to do it manually?

Such as:

```
eval(str(eval(str(a))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a distinction between the symbols and the expressions:

```
import sympy as sy
a, b, c = sy.symbols('a:c')

a_expr = sy.sympify("b + 5")
b_expr = sy.sympify("c + 5")
c_expr = sy.sympify("5")

sy.solve([sy.Eq(a,a_expr), sy.Eq(b,b_expr), sy.Eq(c,c_expr)])
```

yields

```
{c: 5, b: 10, a: 15}
```

---

Above, `a` is a Symbol, but `a_expr` is an expression:

```
In [117]: type(a)
Out[117]: sympy.core.symbol.Symbol

In [118]: type(a_expr)
Out[118]: sympy.core.add.Add
```

---

Given a dict of formulas such as

```
formulas = {'a': 'b+5', 'b': 'c+5', 'c': '5'}
```

you could form the equations with a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
equations = [sy.Eq(sy.symbols(variable), sy.sympify(expr))
             for variable, expr in formulas.items()]
```

and solve the system of equations with

```
solution = sy.solve(equations)
# {c: 5, b: 10, a: 15}
```

---

**Why you should not use `sympy.var`**:

When dealing with dynamic variables -- variables whose names are unknown until
run-time -- it is advisable to avoid using `sy.var`. `sy.var` adds the name of
the variable to the global namespace. The only purpose in doing this is if you
are going to *reference the variable by name*. But by hypothesis the variable
names are unknown until run-time. So the script code should not -- in fact,
should not be able to -- reference the variables by name. So using `sy.var` should be useless if the variables are truly dynamic.

That's no real problem, however. The dynamic variables names (as strings)
can be listed with

```
In [22]: formulas.keys()
Out[22]: ['a', 'c', 'b']
```

and the `sy.Symbols` can be listed with

```
In [23]: solution.keys()
Out[23]: [c, b, a]
```

So you can write loops to access each variable without ever having to define a
global variable name for each Symbol.

Comment: Thanks! Once you understand the concept, it becomes so obvious.
Is there any way of declaring the symbols in a dynamic way (e.g. from a list or dictionary with unknown length)?

Comment: Do you mean you want to declare symbols `a`,`b`,`c` given a list like `['b+5', 'c+5', '5']`? Do you know the variable names which might show up in the list in advance?

Comment: The idea is to be able to calculate a dynamic system. Given e.g. a dictionary {'a': 'b+5', 'b': 'c+5', 'c': '5'}
Is there any way of creating all the symbols for each entry (key) of the dictionary, without knowing beforehand how long the dictionary will be and which names the keys will have?

Comment: After more of investigation, I think that `var()` might be the right choice? 
Something along the lines of `for key in dict: var(key)` and then assigning the equations...

Comment: Solved:
`formulas = {'a': 'b+5', 'b': 'c+5', 'c': '5'} 
equations = []

for key in formulas:
    var(key)
    equations.append(Eq(sympify(key),sympify(formulas[key])))`

Comment: Wow, thanks for the edit which includes the explanation on sympy.var and a solution!